# Eclipse plugin console product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to create a standalone Windows console program with Eclipse without the need of installing a Java-virtual machine on the client. I think the Eclipse RCP Product architecture is the way to go. Can anybody confirm this and point to a good example ?

thanks, Stephan

Comment: Why do you think RCP is the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to run Java application you will have to require JRE installed on the client's machine. However, you can include it with your application, to be sure it is always present. Please see [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html#deployproduct_jre) for more details.